# [Informatica][ODBC 20101 driver][Microsoft SQL Server]Invalid operator for data type. Operator equals minus, type equals varchar

Tags: sql, oracle, informatica

```
REPLACE(T.FirstName, ' ', '') + '.' + 
REPLACE(REPLACE(T.LastName, ' ', ''), '''', '') + '.' + SUBSTRING(CONVERT(varchar(50), T1.Id), 1, 8) +
'@outlook.com' AS 'EmailAddress'
```

`EmailAddress` is the one of the column which has above logic. Informatica workflow failing due to conversion with below error. Can any one help me how to handle this.

Source is SQL Server, and target is Oracle

I get this error:

> [Informatica][ODBC 20101 driver][Microsoft SQL Server]Invalid operator for data type. Operator equals minus, type equals varchar.

Comment: in Oracle concatenation is "||" and not "+"

Comment: You are using Oracle or SqlServer  .. ????

Comment: SQL server is the source and I need to load data to oracle table. And this email column is from source query. Informatica throwing error for this column. I'm thinking it's comparability issue .

Comment: someone has a hyphenated name?

Comment: i ran this SQL with sample values and its working. Is data a problem?
REPLACE('abcd', ' ', '') + '.' + 
REPLACE(REPLACE('pqr', ' ', ''), '''', '') + '.' + SUBSTRING(CONVERT(varchar(50), 'xx'), 1, 8) +
'@outlook.com' AS 'EmailAddress'

Comment: Query runs perfectly fine in SQL server !! When it comes to source qualifier  (I'm using the same sqlserver query in source qualifier).  - informatica throwing the error for this expression.           Sample data in source from this query kim-jo.husa.12345678@outlook.com

Comment: This can be ODBC error. To check if this related to ODBC - you can dump data from sql server into a file and use the file to read from. This can also be related to UTF data - like chinese, hindi, french, japnese. To test it, may be keep only 100rows in source and see if thats working. If yes, it means, its a data issue.

Answer (score 0):

This is not Informatica error. This is an error thrown by MS SQL Server and passes on to Informatica.

This means, the error is thrown by the query. Debug the query on your source system. It seems it some part results in a minus that is then interpreted as substraction by the Query Optimizer.

Answer (score 0):

```
 {FN CONCAT( {FN CONCAT({FN CONCAT({FN CONCAT( {FN CONCAT(REPLACE(T.FirstName,' ',''), '.')}, REPLACE(REPLACE(
      T.LastName,' ',''),'''',''))},'.' )}, SUBSTRING(convert(varchar(50),T1.PersonId),1,8))},'@Outlook.com')} AS 'EmailAddress'
```

Made the changes as above. SQL Server doesnt have any issue with '+' or 'CONCAT'. inforamtica was throwing error for '+' for concatenation in query. Now im able to load the data to Oracle table from SQL Server. Thanks all for the responses and help.